# Open office documents on windows 10 UWP (Phone)

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have a windows 10 UWP app that will display a list of office documents to the user. When user clicks one of these documents, I want to launch the existing office apps on the device to view and edit that document. What is the best way to achieve it. I'm new to windows 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`Launcher.LaunchFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync.aspx) method to launch the existing office apps to view and edit office documents. For example, using `LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile)` method starts the app associated with the specified file:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve document for LocalFolder
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Test.docx");

    if (file != null)
    {
        // Launch the retrieved file
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
}
```

Besides this, we can also use `LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile, LauncherOptions)` method. This method starts the default app associated with the specified file, using the specified options. Such as we can call this method with `LauncherOptions.DisplayApplicationPicker` set to `true` to launch the app that the user selects from the "Open With" dialog box. For more information, see [Launch the default app for a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299102.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for response! This is exactly what I am doing. The problem is instead of a file name, I will have a path, I need to first save the file locally on the phone(after downloading from cloud) to a particular path and then open it from there. GetFileAsync doesn't seem to take a path. I'm wondering what is the best pattern in UWP to download and open a file.

Comment: @SurenderS: What's the particular path you want to use? I think you can store the file in the application‘s local folder and then retrieve it with the file name like what I did in my sample.

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful!

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Do you happen to know a simple example of programmatically editing a WORD document  in a UWP app? Or, it's even possible?